# Is it possible to attach `kinit` to the first attempt to `ssh` without a Kerberos ticket?

Tags: command-line, ssh, kerberos

My university uses Kerberos-based authentication for login to our unix servers.

One way to get passwordless login is to run `kinit`, type my password, and then run `ssh@host`.

For this setup, I do the following inside my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host SchoolHost1 SchoolHost2
    GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

My question is, can I skip the `kinit` step and run `ssh` directly , in such a way that the first attempt to `ssh` will automatically grab a kerberos ticket so that subsequent attempts to `ssh` will have the ticket and not require a password?

Update: Public Key login is **not** supported by the University's system, because the server cannot read `authorized_keys` file before the login. This is a property of the `Kerberos / AFS` system for which there is really no workaround.

Comment: Can you not just exchange the pub/private keys for SSH and login using those instead?

Comment: The whole reason why I am going through this Kerberos crap is because the University's machines do not support public keys login.

Answer (score 2):

On your laptop, I'd redefine `ssh` in your `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bashrc` file

```
ssh () 
{ 
    kinit -R || kinit -r 8days
    command ssh "$@"
}
```

to refresh your ticket if possible, otherwise make a fresh one - if your AFS site policy agrees.

Public key login is possible but only as a last resort if you really truly cannot Kerberize your laptop - on the ssh server, move secret keys (if any) from `~/.ssh/` to `~/.ssh/private/`, `chmod 700` and `fs setacl` to secure your private keys, `fs listacl ~/.ssh/private/` to double check only you have access, finally make `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` world readable so `sshd` can see them to log you in - but until you do something like `( kinit -R || kinit -r 8days ) && aklog; klist` you'll lack AFS access - so `scp` can see `/tmp/` but not `/afs/` - if you work out how to get tickets after `scp` logs in and before it accesses files, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a quick script:

```
#!/bin/bash

klist || kinit

ssh user@host
```

Put this in your `PATH` and run it instead of ssh.

This works by using the `klist` utility.  If you have no active tickets, then `klist` will fail and `kinit` will be run.  If you have an active ticket, then `klist` will succeed and `kinit` will not be run.

I haven't tested this thoroughly, so there are probably enormous problems with it.

Comment: I think you want to add the option -s to the klist, which suppresses it printing out output when you do have a valid key. I made an alias ssh='klist -s || kinit && ssh' which seems to be working, but there may well be problems I haven't caught